# How to iterate a list from flash message in jinja template in python-flask

Tags: python, html, list, flask, jinja2

I want to iterate a list passed in jinja template using flask flash

Python :

```
@app.route("/result")
def test():
    my_list = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
    flash(my_list)
    return render_template("temp.html")
```

HTML :

```
{% with items=get_flashed_messages() %}
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
<li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endwith %}
```

Result :

```
 - ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
```

Expected:

```
 - item1
 - item2
 - item3
 - item4
```

How I can achieve my expected result using flash function, Please let me know, I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash each "item" individually. `get_flashed_messages()` returns a list of the messages you've passed from your server.

```py
@app.route("/result")
def test():
    flash("item1")
    flash("item2")
    flash("item3")
    flash("item4")
    return render_template("temp.html")
```